# Why doesn't my JavaScript code work properly to update select options?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, foreach

I want to use JavaScript in an update feature. If a user chooses `Ya` in the first `select` then the second `select` should show the options `ontime` and `terlambat` only, but if the user chooses `Tidak` then the second select should only show `sakit`, `Tanpa Keterangan`, and `ijin`.

But this code only works for the oldest user id and does not work for any other user id. What is the problem?

```js
function absen(el) {
  var x = el.value;

  if (x == '1') {
    document.getElementById('ontime_update').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('terlambat_update').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('sakit_update').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('tk_update').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('ijin_update').style.display = 'none';
    $('#backup').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#keterangan').removeAttr("disabled");
  } else if (x == '0') {
    document.getElementById('ontime_update').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('terlambat_update').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('sakit_update').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('tk_update').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('ijin_update').style.display = 'block';
    $('#backup').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#keterangan').removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $('#backup').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#keterangan').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <div class=”col-md-2-mb-5″>
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Kehadiran</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select name="hadir" id="hadir_update" class="form-control select2" onchange="absen(this)" required>
        <option selected value="">Pilih Kehadiran</option>
        <option value="1" {{ $row->hadir == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Ya</option>
        <option value="0" {{ $row->hadir == '0' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Tidak</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=”col-md-6″ style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <div class=”col-md-2″>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Keterangan</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <select value name="keterangan" id="keterangan" class="form-control select2">
          <option value="">Pilih Keterangan</option>
          <option id='ontime_update' {{ $row->keterangan == 'ontime' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="ontime">On Time</option>
          <option id='terlambat_update' {{ $row->keterangan == 'terlambat' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="terlambat">Terlambat</option>
          <option id="ijin_update" {{ $row->keterangan == 'ijin' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="ijin">Ijin</option>
          <option id="sakit_update" {{ $row->keterangan == 'sakit' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="sakit">Sakit</option>
          <option id="tk_update" {{ $row->keterangan == 'tk' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="tk">Tanpa Keterangan</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this "row" being repeated? If so, you're breaking one of the most fundamental rules of HTML: `id` values **must be unique on the page**. Use a unique value for each row, perhaps using `class` to identify things within the row.

Comment: oohh, I remember that, wait I will using class to identify

Comment: Also, when posting questions about HTML, CSS, or JavaScript here on Stack Overflow, please don't show the template your server-side code understands; instead, show an example ("[mcve]") of its output, because that's what the browser sees and the CSS and JavaScript operate on.

Comment: I have using document.getElementsByClassName but it's still not working, any suggestion?

Comment: I'am doing that to select automatic when user will update/edit that matching with id selected, but I have try to deleted that and the javascript code still not working